# PyDev console input issue

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I implemented a Python 3 program which reads user input with e.g. 
`w = input("Enter a word:")`. Then I run this program in PyDev 
(Eclipse with PyDev). Each time the user (of my program) enters a word, 
the program prints out some output, and then ask for another word.

But when it asks for another word the marker is not positioned properly, 
i.e. it's not after the `Enter a word:` string in the console. So the user 
has to click with the mouse (after `Enter a word:`), and only then enter the word.

When I run the same program outside of PyDev (just in the Windows cmd prompt with `python.exe`), then the program prompts properly, the marker is properly positioned after `Enter a word:`.

Is this a known bug in PyDev or what is it? 
Could this possibly be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code ? How does your code ask for another word to input?

Comment: @reportgunner Well, in the same way... `w = input("Enter a word:")` is in a loop so... That's how it asks for another word.

Comment: So did you mean that PyDev console window loses focus after you hit Enter ? Can you test this without using `input()` and see if the focus is lost the same ?

Comment: It's not losing focus. Just the marker is not after `Enter a word:`.

Comment: I added a picture. See... the marker is before the underlined `isolate` word and not after `Enter new word:`.

Comment: The screenshot helped a ton, thank you. So you `print()` after the `input()` ?

Comment: Yeah, normally you take input, you compute something, you print it, and then you take another input and so on. Just a basic loop-based program.